# How to 'rasterize' type in Ai: convert the type objects to actual objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have an illustration made out of letters. I want to turn those letterforms into normal objects, as in not type objects. I want to do this so any machine will be able to print my work, even if it doesn't have the fonts I used.

Comment: "Rasterize" means convert to something stored as numeric representations of pixels with a set resolution. It sounds like you want to convert to outlines which will keep the objects as vector (i.e. curves stored as mathematical formulas, resolution independant)

Comment: @Yorik notice the quotes around the word 'rasterize'. It's only being used as a description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- select your type object;
- <kbd>Type > Create Outlines</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (as in the letter O, not a zero);
- ungroup if necessary.